# Looping in mysql java - searching templates

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop

I have a table in mysql that contain a field called template. 
I have one template stored in a variable, I need to compare that variable with each of the other templates found in the table until a match is found. I dont know how to retrieve one template from the database row at a time, compare it and if it does not match, move to next row to compare again and so on until match is found. I am new to mysql looping, please help.

```
Connection con = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement st;
        st = con.prepareStatement("select template from tbl1 ");

        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) { 

     String dbTemplate = result.getString("template");
               if x == dbtemplate

                } else {// move to next row? How to say do the loop for next row in table??


                }
```

Comment: Why not use a where clause in your SQL statement?

Comment: No I cant use a where clause here, I need to verify each row with the template stored in the variable, row by row. Any idea of how i set the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.next()` any way gets next row. All you need to do would do condition check inside and if condition satisfied, then only execute the functionality you want.

```
 while (result.next()) { 
               if(yourConditionSatisfied) {
              //All your logic goes here.  If you want to break the lookup, just add break here.      
            }

     }
```

Comment: Ok but is my select command correct? 
I mean will it select all the templates and compare it until it matches?

Comment: You always could go with harder approach, it's up to you. But, IMHO, it would be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Ask SQL to check it for you, Try this:

```
st = con.prepareStatement("select template from tbl1 where template = ?");
st.setString(1, "template_name");
```

Then you would only have results that templates matches

Comment: No actually i cant compare the template names, i need to compare each template from each row with the variable

Comment: So, write your variable here: st.setString(1, div_variable), does it make sense?

Comment: I need to go row by row untill the end of the table if no match is found